# Pomelo MySql .net core 2 - default execution timeout

Tags: mysql, .net-core-2.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

we are using Pomelo MySql in production environment for half a year and it works just fine but occassionally we are getting exception like so:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: The Command Timeout expired before the operation completed.
```

Connection string in appsettings.json looks like this:

"MySqlConnection": "server=somesql;userid=user;password=pass;database=test;"

so nothing fancy.

My question is what is the default command execution timeout in pomelo?
How can I change it through connection string?

Executing code like this inside DbContext

```
var timeout = Database.GetCommandTimeout();
```

gives me always null value.

Answer (score 7):

Try increasing the command timeout (in seconds) in your connection string by specifying  `default command timeout`.

In your case your connection string should look like:

```
server=somesql;userid=user;password=pass;database=test;default command timeout=120;
```